# pyTransitions trigger() method blocks

Tags: python, pytransitions

I have a fairly complex application involving a GUI front-end and several other classes, several of which are state machines based on the excellent [pytransitions](https://github.com/pytransitions/transitions) library.
The application hangs at various times, and being multi-threaded it is difficult to debug, but I have reproduced a minimal example here:

```
from transitions import Machine
import time

States = ["OFF", "ON"]
Transitions = [{"trigger": "PowerUp", "source": "OFF", "dest": "ON"}]

class GUI:
    def __init__(self):
        self.machine1 = Machine_1(self)
        self.machine2 = Machine_2(self)

    def on_button_pressed(self):
        self.machine2.trigger("PowerUp")
        self.machine1.trigger("PowerUp")


class Machine_1:
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.parent = parent
        self.fsm = Machine(model=self, states=States, transitions=Transitions, initial="OFF")

    def on_enter_ON(self):
        print("machine1 is on!")
        self.parent.machine2.signal = True


class Machine_2:
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.parent = parent
        self.fsm = Machine(model=self, states=States, transitions=Transitions, initial="OFF")
        self.signal = False

    def on_enter_ON(self):
        print("machine2 waits for machine1 ...")
        while self.signal is False:
            time.sleep(0.1)
        print("machine2 on!")
```

i.e. When machine1 is "turned on", it sends a signal to machine2. machine2 must wait for this signal before executing its logic for the "on" state.

Using the Python REPL as the main loop:

```
>>> import test
>>> gui = test.GUI()        
>>> gui.machine1.state      
'off'
>>> gui.machine2.state      
'off'
>>> gui.on_button_pressed()
machine2 waits for machine1 ...
(never returns)
```

machine2 is stuck in its while loop, waiting for the signal from machine1, which never arrives because machine1 is never triggered.

If I re-order the sequence of triggers in `gui.on_button_pressed()`:

```
self.machine1.trigger("PowerUp")
self.machine2.trigger("PowerUp")
```

... everything works:

```
>>> gui.on_button_pressed()
machine1 is on!
machine2 waits for machine1 ...
machine2 is on!
```

What is going on here? Is the `trigger()` method supposed to block? Is it documented somewhere, when does it return? Or am I using the `on_enter_state` callbacks in an unsupported way? Is there a recommended pattern I should be using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The core `Machine` of `pytransitions` is neither threaded nor asynchronous. This means that when a callback does not return, the whole event processing and thus the trigger function  will block. There are a variety of ways to deal with this. Which way to chose depends on your architecture. Providing MWE for all approaches is a bit too much for a SO answer but I can briefly outline how solutions could look like.

#### Event-driven

Since `Machine_1` already has a reference to `Machine_2` and `Machine_2` is waiting for an event from `Machine_1`, you could model that transition explicitly:

```py
Transitions = [{"trigger": "PowerUp", "source": "OFF", "dest": "ON"}]
# ...
self.machine2 = Machine_2(self)
self.machine2.add_transition("Machine1PoweredUp", "OFF", "ON")
# ... 
    def on_enter_ON(self):
        print("machine1 is on!")
        self.parent.machine2.Machine1PoweredUp()
```

Note that when you have machines that share the same states and transitions, you can use ONE machine and multiple models.

```py
def Model_1():

    def on_enter_ON(self):
        # a dispatched event is forwarded to all models attached to the 
        # machine in question. We consider `parent` to be such a machine here.
        self.parent.dispatch("Machine1PoweredUp")

s1 = Model_1()
s2 = Model_2()
# we set `ignore_invalid_triggers` since `s1` need to process the fired
# event as well even though it is already in state `ON`
m = Machine(model=[s1, s2], ignore_invalid_triggers=True)
s1.parent = m
s1.PowerUp()
```

You can use the shared machine as some sort of 'event bus' which can reduce coupling and dependencies.

#### Polling

Instead of blocking in your main loop, you could make `Machine_2` 'attempt' a transition with a condition and return. Conditions can either be the name of a model method or a reference to a callable. Since `pytransitions` always adds convenience state check functions to models, we can just pass the state check `is_ON` from `machine1` to the transition definition. The condition will halt and return when the condition is not met, enabling a sequential workflow.

```py
self.machine2.add_transition("PowerUp", "OFF", "ON", conditions=machine1.is_ON)
# ...

while not machine2.is_ON:
  time.sleep(0.1)
  machine2.PowerUp()
```

You should note though, that when `on_enter_<state>` callbacks are executed, the machine/model is already considered to be in that state. For your particular use case that would mean that `machine1.is_ON` returns `True` even though the `on_enter_ON` callback of `Machine_1` is still processed.

#### Threading

You could create a thread for your machine 1 state check in machine 2 as well. To 'unblock' the transition, I'd suggest adding a temporary state such as `Booting` to show that `Machine_2` is not ready yet.

```py
class Machine_2:

    def check_state(self):
        while self.signal is False:
            time.sleep(0.1)
        self.Machine1Ready()  # transition from 'Booting' to 'ON'

    def on_enter_ON(self):
        print("machine2 on!")

    def on_enter_BOOTING(self):
        print("machine2 waits for machine1 ...")
        threading.Thread(target=self.check_state).start()
```

`transitions` features a `LockedMachine` in case multiple threads need to access the same machine. However, threaded access to state machines has some pitfalls and is considerably harder to debug in my experience.

#### Asynchronous

Here is a short example of how `AsyncMachine` could be used to achieve something like this. This example is for illustrative purposes and should not be reproduced that way:

```py
from transitions.extensions.asyncio import AsyncMachine
import asyncio


class Model1:

    done = False

    async def on_enter_ON(self):
        await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
        print("Machine 1 done")
        self.done = True


model1 = Model1()


class Model2:

    done = False

    async def on_enter_ON(self):
        while not model1.done:
            print("Machine 1 not ready yet")
            await asyncio.sleep(0.05)
        print("Machine 2 done")


model2 = Model2()

m = AsyncMachine(model=[model1, model2], states=["OFF", "ON"], initial="OFF")
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(model1.to_ON(), model2.to_ON()))
```